# Как получить положение окна в Compose Desktop?

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop

Подскажите, как получить положение окна?

Пробовал так:

```
val posX = remember { mutableStateOf(WindowState().position) }
Text(
    "  ${posX.value.y} ${posX.value.x}",
    fontSize = 24.sp,
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(onClick = { "  ${posX.value.y} ${posX.value.x}"})
)
```

Получаю:

```
"Dp.Unspecified Dp.Unspecified"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы подписаться на изменения `WindowState`, создайте объект `WindowState` с помощью метода `rememberWindowState()` и передайте его в `Window`:

```kotlin
val windowState = rememberWindowState()
Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication, state = windowState) {
    Text("Window position: ${windowState.position}")
}
```